# sybase sql column concatenation conditionally

Tags: sql, sybase

Please help me in concatenation the columns,

```
Col1 Col2 col3
 a    b    c
 a3   null null
```

Expected output is :

```
col1:a col2:b col3:c
col1:a3
```

expected is Do not include null column name and value both.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ + http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/ + http://idownvotedbecau.se/nomcve/

Comment: which Sybase product (ASE? SQLAnywhere? IQ? Advantage?) and what version? what query(s) have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one method:

```
select stuff( coalesce('col1:' + col1, ' ') +
              coalesce('col2:' + col2, ' ') +
              coalesce('col3:' + col3, ' '),
              1, 1, ''
            ) as concatted_values
```